# Are the Windows factory reset files stored on the ROM of laptops shipped with Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, operating-systems, reset

Was just wondering since I have a Dell laptop which came shipped with windows, I've installed several version of Linux on it and have always had the option to factory reset it to Windows through the BIOS.

Can't find anything on this question online so maybe someone here can satisfy my curiosity.

To clarifiy: I don't require any urgent help, I am only asking out of curiosity since I haven't found an answer online.

Comment: The recovery system depends on the recovery partition. If you kept it then recovery should work.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Hiya. Yeah I figured as much. But what about the 'Erase disk' options that, for example, Linux Mint or Ubuntu give you when installing? Apparently they didn't mess with the (perhaps) hidden partition where the Windows reset files are stored.

Comment: No, they did if chosen. That said, the recovery partition can be in a different drive than the one you're erasing.

Comment: If the partition exists it might still be possible, but you gain absolutely nothing from using it, there is nothing special about the recovery partition created by the OEM.  It is far easier to just install the current version of Windows from a bootable installation media.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.